# Catch Ctrl+Alt keys in wndproc

Tags: c++, qt

I have successfully caught <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> inside my overridden `wndproc` function using:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND hwnd,
UINT uMsg,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_F4:
        {
            qDebug() << "Alt+F4 pressed";
            break;
        }

    };

}
else
    return CallWindowProc(OldWinProc,hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

I now need to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

But I can't seem to find them. 
I know in C# one of the parameters in the function is:

```
Keys keyData
```

And I can use the following:

```
case Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Q:
```

How do I get those key combinations in C++?

Comment: You absolutely don't want to do that. If you want kiosk mode then use WIndows' support for that. If you want your own single app OS then build one based on Linux source.

Comment: I need to create hotkeys for certain functionality in our application and I'm trying to catch them here since something like Ctrl+Alt+Left rotates the application but I need to use that key combination to scroll left on a graph for example

Comment: Catching ALt-F4 is generally the wrong thing to do. You want to catch WM_CLOSE, which can be generated in multiple ways including Alt-F4 but also `Alt-space, Arrow up, Return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetKeyState` `WinAPI` function to get state of modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. For example:

```
case VK_LEFT:
  {
     if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)
     {
        qDebug() << "Alt+Ctrl+Left Arrow pressed";
        break;
     }
  }
```

But please take in account that some videocard drivers under `Windows` can rotate screen on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> combination and intercept this combination before your code gets it. And it will be a bit hard to implement getting this keyboard event before driver. However you can [disable this feature](https://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: just pressing Alt+Left Arrow gets me into that case, but as soon as I pressing Ctrl+Alt+Left Arrow then windows rotates my screen...It doesn't even reach that case

Comment: It is your videocard driver that rotates the screen on `Ctrl+Alt+Left Arrow` combination. It will be a bit hard to get keyboard event before driver. Hovewer you can disable this feature http://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Thank you, I did not even think that videocard drivers will grab key presses before Windows. Do you mind mentioning it in your answer? I'm marking your answer as accepted.